# Error "delete method of range class failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and delete rows starting with value "#" in my worksheet and i get the below error every time i try to delete row found.

> Delete method of range class failed 1004"

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

        Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "#*"

        Set FoundCell = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
            'MsgBox (FoundCell.Row)
            FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete ' giving error "delete method of range class failed" here.
        Else
            MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
        End IF
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine, can you share your worksheet data and point in which instance you are getting this error

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in that row? Or any controls like ActiveX controls or buttons? Any PivotTable or ListObject tables in this row? Can you delete this row manuall? Please check.

Comment: Yes, there was a row which i couldn't delete manually. Thank you!